# Azure network communication between instances of the same role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-virtual-network

Can multiple role instances of the same role can talk to each other by obtaining VIP (Virtual IP) address for a specific endpoint listened by all those instances from `RoleEnvironment`? If so, is returned VIP can be load balanced to the caller (of `RoleEnvironment` methods) instance itself.

Comment: "Yes" is the answer to your first question, if you mean "by obtaining the IP address for each instance". See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstanceendpoint.ipendpoint.aspx). I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Assume you have roleA and its instances roleA_in1 & roleA_in2. When _in1 asks for endpoint IP and sends let's say TCP packages to it and meanwhile these instances are listening that port, can load balancer route the TCP traffic to the same instance itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Role instances can talk to each other via internal endpoints. Unlike input endpoints, they are only visible to other instances within a deployment (regardless of the role).

Talking directly, via internal endpoint, bypasses the external-VIP load balancer completely. So, if you have three worker role instances that you're trying to connect to (say that's where your REST service resides), you'd have to do your own load-balancing across the 3 instances.

Working with internal endpoints is just as straightforward as input endpoints. First set one up:
[image]

Then grab one at random. For example (by the crudest sense of the word):

```cs
        var random = new Random();
        var role = RoleEnvironment.Roles["WorkerRole1"];
        var instanceNumber = random.Next() % role.Instances.Count;
        var ipendpoint = role.Instances[instanceNumber].InstanceEndpoints["myservice"].IPEndpoint;
        var address = ipendpoint.Address;
        var port = ipendpoint.Port;
```

Note: You can still reach out to an input endpoint on any role, from any role. At that point, you'll be load-balanced just like any other traffic coming from the outside world. And you'll have to worry about security as well (whereas with internal endpoints you don't).

Comment: Great answer David, thanks. Two extra questions: How would you **prevent** an instance to obtain its own endpoint? Right now you are choosing it randomly, if you get IP of the current instance and make a request to that service, does that request go out of your machine and routed to internal network? (because it is not supposed to do I guess.)

Comment: With cloud services (web/worker role instances), you're in complete control. If you don't define internal endpoints, then none are opened up and the instances can't talk to each other. If you don't define input (external) endpoints, you can't have traffic reach your instances from the outside world. Completely up to you.

Comment: No, you got me wrong. Let's say you have 3 role instances with all listening to a single **internal** endpoint. (1) How do you prevent an instance to get its own IP from `RoleEnvironment`? (2) If you get your own IP address from `RoleEnvironment` and access service via this IP:Port, does the network packets leave that instance VM and come back from router or not? (I think they shouldn't but I'm not sure.)