# Azure Role Connectivity for Scaled Roles

Tags: azure

I've seen examples of getting the current IP of an Instance for a Role but wasn't sure if this could be achieved by "DNS" rather than querying the environment for each api call.

We have a cloud service "ourapp" that contains 2 web roles

- "frontend" with an input endpoint (443)
- "api" with an internal endpoint (8080)

The "frontend" gets it data from the "api".

Both roles are set to autoscale based on CPU load.

We expect the "frontend" to scale-up more than the "api" as we have used caching for some of the data from the "api"

Is it possible to for example put into the web.config of the "frontend" the url for the "api" based on a name e.g.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ApiUrl" value="http://api:8080"/>
</appSettings>
```

or

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ApiUrl" value="http://ourapp.cloudapp.net:8080"/>
</appSettings>
```

The documentation on Azure talks about internal azure name resolution but doesn't give any examples. I've tried using the Role Name and various connotations but it never finds the "api".

Comment: You really should use name resolution. As we talk about cloud and scaling, you never be sure where exactly your service will be hosted. What do you mean by "never finds the api"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand - you want implement internal communication between 2 auto-scaled workers with random number of instances. As far as I know it's dead end. You can treat URL address as link to worker load balancer (rather than concrete worker instance) and Azure load balancing is working only for external endpoints.

Please find scenarios below:

- Chose random Api worker instance ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325521/2275775))
- Implement asynchronous communication between "frontend" and "api". It's great solution for messaging experience between many "frontend" instances and "api" instances ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589781.aspx))
- Use external cache instead of api worker if cache is main responsibility of "api" as you mentioned ([link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/))